# records are not added in Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem , i am building a simple PHP form page with Mysql data base all thing working great but database is not showing(adding) records more than one , as there is only one row more roes are not adding , dont knw why?

here is the code

```
<?php include("Removing_error_func.php") ?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
Password: <input type="password" name="pass"><br>
Type Password Again: <input type="password" name="passAgain"><br>
Cell number:<input type="text" name="cell"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
$error_arr=array();
$validation_pass=false;

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST")
{
    clean_data($_POST["name"]);
    clean_data($_POST["email"]);
    clean_data($_POST["cell"]);
    clean_data($_POST["pass"]);
    clean_data($_POST["passAgain"]);

if((!isset($_POST["name"])||$_POST["name"]=="")&&(!isset($_POST["email"])||$_POST["email"]=="")&&(!isset($_POST["cell"])||$_POST["cell"]=="")&&(!isset($_POST["pass"])||$_POST["pass"]=="")&&(!isset($_POST["passAgain"])||$_POST["passAgain"]==""))
{
$error_arr["blank form"]="The form is blank";
$validation_pass=false;
}
else
{

    if(!isset($_POST["name"])||$_POST["name"]=="")
    $error_arr['Empty Name field']="Name field is empty";

    if(!isset($_POST["email"])||$_POST["email"]=="")
    $error_arr['Empty Email field']="Email field is empty";

    if(!isset($_POST["cell"])||$_POST["cell"]=="")
    $error_arr['Empty Cell field']="Cell number field is empty";

    if(!isset($_POST["pass"])||$_POST["pass"]=="")
    $error_arr['Empty pass field']="Password field is empty";

    if(!isset($_POST["passAgain"])||$_POST["passAgain"]=="")
    $error_arr['Empty passAgain field']="\"Type password field is empty\"";


if(valid_data($_POST["name"],"n")==0)
    $error_arr["Username"]="Only letters and white space allowed in Name field";

    if(valid_data($_POST["email"],"e")==0)
    $error_arr["Email"]="Invalid email format";

    if(valid_data($_POST["cell"],"c")==0)
    $error_arr["Cell numeber"]="invalid phone number";  

    if(valid_data($_POST["pass"],"p")==0)
    $error_arr["pass_err"]="Password is not valid as per giver instructions!";

}

if($_POST["pass"]!=$_POST["passAgain"])
$error_arr["pass_match_err"]="Password doesn't match";


}

if(!empty($error_arr))
{
    echo "<div class=\"Error\">";
    echo "Please fix the fowllowing error:";
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach($error_arr as $key => $error)
    echo "<li>{$error}</li>";
    echo "</ul>";
    echo "</div>";

}
else
$validation_pass=true;




$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","first");

// Check connection
if($validation_pass===true)
{
if ((mysqli_connect_errno()) )
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  else
  {
      if(($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST")&& $validation_pass===true)
      {
      mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO user_pannel (id, user_name,user_email,password,user_contact)
VALUES (1, '$_POST[name]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[pass]','$_POST[cell]')");

  echo "query submitted";
  }
  }
}
else
{
echo "validation not pass";
mysqli_close($con);
}
?> 


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have a gaping wide-open [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability, and are simply assuming your query can never failed. Both are horribly bad. I'm guessing the lack of record insertion is due to the hard-coded id `1` in your query, causing primary key violations - which, if you'd had *ANY* kind of error handling on the query, you'd have been told about.

Comment: maybe it is not possible to add $_POST["name"] in the way you do it in your query code. try "INSERT INTO ..." . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["email"]) . ", " . etc. to protect yourself from sql-injections like Marc B states.

Comment: And I'm just going to leave this here http://www.phptherightway.com/#databases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your `insert` statement:

```
  mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO user_pannel (id, user_name,user_email,password,user_contact)
                          VALUES (1, '$_POST[name]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[pass]','$_POST[cell]')");
```

You are inserting a fixed value into the `id` field.  Now, in most tables, the `id` column is a primary key.  In better designed tables, it is an auto-incremented primary key.  You shouldn't be assigning the value in the `insert`; the database should do that for you.

This is speculation, of course, because you are not trapping the error as @MarcB points out in a comment.  But this would be one reason why multiple inserts would fail.

And, if Marc answers the question, you should accept his answer.  I missed the explanation in the second half of the comment.